# Can't center my header

Tags: html, css

having a very hard time getting my header image to be centered.

```
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Genova, sans-serif;
    background-color:#000;  
}

divWrapper {
    width:700px;
    margin:20px auto;
}

divHeader {
    width:700px;
    background-color:#999;
}
```

and my html...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Just Messing Around</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="divWrapper">
<div id="divHeader"><img src="raiderd.png" width="405" height="68"/></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

just seems to stay stuck in the top left no matter what i do...

Answer (score 2):

the "#" for IDs are missing

```
#divWrapper {
    width:700px;
    margin:20px auto;
}

#divHeader {
    width:700px;
    background-color:#999;
}
```

Comment: well i feel like an idiot...everything is centered, however now my background is white instead of black and i did not change anything but #'s for the id's...

Comment: You didn't put a `#` before `body`, did you?

Answer (score 0):

The image won't be centered just because you have two nested  tags of the same width. You might try using ...

```
#divHeader img {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

<div id="divHeader"><img src="raiderd.png" width="405" height="68"/></div>
```

Truthfully, I forget (and I'm eating dinner). It all depends on what the final look of the header div will be. Everything centered? In that case, I might put `text-align:center;` on the `<div>` . You should get it by tinkering, though.

Answer (score 0):

Above is true, also the `#divHeader` needs to have `margin: auto;` width must be smaller than the wrapper..

Check out this Jsfiddle. Change the text for your image and increase the `divHeader` width to be the size of your image (must still be less than your wrapper).

http://jsfiddle.net/f5yGQ/

```
body{
    width:90%;
}

#divWrapper {
   width:700px;
   background-color:#999;
   margin:auto;
}

#divHeader {
    width:20px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can ignore the body attribute